# Understanding Covering Spaces of $S^1 \vee S^1$

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I'm trying to understand the covering space of $S^1 \vee S^1$ as seen in Hatcher. For example, let's see this one: [image]

From this, what I'm not understanding is:

1. What does $<a, b^2, bab^{-1}>$ mean here exactly?
2. So we want to give a map $l \colon X \to S^1 \vee S^1$. Is $X$ a wedge of three circles?
3. In class, we said that the only deck transformation of the covering map is identity and rotation by $\pi$. But what does rotation by $\pi$ mean here?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: For your first question, that group presentation is the subgroup $p_*(\pi_1(\tilde{X},\tilde{x}_0))\subset\pi_1(S^1\vee S^1,x_0)$, where $p_*$ is induced by the covering map... The second question seems unclear to me,what do you mean by "is $X$ a wedge of three circles"? Which one is $X$? For your third question, well, in the group of deck transformation of this covering space, there exists an identity element and one operation. I think that rotation by $\pi$ probably means "a reflection".

Comment: @Kevin.S so for first one, I guess I'm having trouble seeing how group presentation gives a topological space. And for the second one, I mean X by what you denote by $X$ with tilda on it.